# Scaling pdf from any size to Letter

Tags: c#, pdf, azure-form-recognizer

My web application lets users upload pdf documents, however the page size is sometimes random.  I need a pdf library that can take (for example) a 17" x 22" document and scale it to Letter size (8.5" x 11").  I've looked at a number of existing PDF libraries and they don't provide this functionality.  I'm uploading the pdf to Azure Form Recognizer and they have limits on the size and resolution of the pdf.

Comment: you can try https://selectpdf.com/demo/pdf-resize.aspx

Comment: Hey, thanks.  That was perfect.  Just tested the Nuget package and it worked.  Much appreciated.